# nginx + php5-fpm + htdocs on USB

Tags: usb, php, nginx

None of the configurations that I've looked up can help with setting up Nginx to serve PHP files on a mounted USB folder. I'm currently getting `file not found` when I try and access a PHP file on the USB but PHP displays correctly when accessing it on the default folder `/usr/share/nginx/www`.

In other words, If I have a `test.php` in `/media/usb/downloads/` and try to access `sitename.com/usb/test.php` I get `file not found`. But, if i place it in `/usr/share/nginx/www/` it works. In both cases, static files work fine.

I have installed nginx and php5-fpm with defaults but added the following changes:

**nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
location /usb/ {
    alias /media/usb/downloads/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    #deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a strong suspicion that this is happening because the `location ~ \.php$` directive is sending the `http://sitename.com/usb/index.php` request as is to `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` and it doesn't find a `/usb/` directory on the server.

Have you considered using a link (`ln`) called `usb` in our root directory to `/media/usb/downloads` instead using the `location` alias?

Comment: Perfect!! I used a symbolic link and it worked! I wish there was better documentation on how to actually do this through the nginx configuration files.